# Numba cannot determine type of loop iterator

Tags: python, numpy, numba, numpy-slicing

In this script Im trying do calculate the normals of some triangles and combine the arrays. Because an other part of the programm is really slow I tried to speed it up with numba.

```
import numpy as np
from numba.experimental import jitclass


RES = 17
POINTS = np.array([
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 0, 1],
            [1, 0, 0],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 1, 0],
            [1, 1, 1],
        ], dtype=np.int8)
EDGES = np.array([
    [0, 1],
    [1, 3],
    [3, 2],
    [2, 0],
    [4, 5],
    [5, 7],
    [7, 6],
    [6, 4],
    [0, 4],
    [1, 5],
    [3, 7],
    [2, 6],
]    )
TRIANGULATIONS = np.array([
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 8, 8, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 0, 0, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, 3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 1, 2, 11, 9, 1, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 2, 2, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 2, 3, 8, 10, 2, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 3, 3, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 0, 1, 10, 8, 0, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 3, 0, 9, 11, 3, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 10, 8, 8, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 1, 4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 4, 9, 1, 7, 4, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 8, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 11, 7, 4, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, 0, 9, 1, 4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 4, 4, 1, 7, 7, 1, 2, 7, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 3, 3, 4, 0, 10, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 9, 9, 2, 0, 7, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 9, 7, 9, 2, 9, 10, 2, 3, 7, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 3, 3, 10, 11, 4, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 0, 7, 0, 1, 10, 7, 0, 10, 7, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 9, 3, 0, 9, 11, 3, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 11, 4, 9, 11, 9, 10, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 3, 9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 8, 4, 5, 3, 8, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, 5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 0, 0, 11, 8, 5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 0, 0, 5, 1, 11, 3, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 8, 2, 8, 4, 5, 2, 8, 5, 2, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 8, 1, 10, 2, 5, 9, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 5, 10, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 3, 3, 5, 10, 3, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 10, 10, 3, 1, 4, 5, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 9, 10, 0, 1, 10, 8, 0, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 10, 4, 10, 3, 10, 11, 3, 0, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 5, 10, 8, 10, 11, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 9, 0, 3, 5, 9, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 7, 1, 1, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 7, 7, 9, 8, 2, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 0, 5, 0, 11, 0, 2, 11, 7, 5, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 3, 7, 0, 8, 7, 1, 0, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 1, 11, 7, 1, 7, 5, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 9, 9, 7, 5, 2, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 1, 3, 9, 0, 3, 5, 9, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 0, 10, 0, 8, 7, 10, 0, 7, 10, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 7, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 8, 5, 8, 7, 1, 10, 3, 10, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 0, 0, 10, 11, 0, 11, 7, 0, 7, 5, 0, 5, 9, -1],
[8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 5, 0, 5, 10, 0, 10, 11, 0, 11, 3, -1],
[5, 11, 7, 10, 11, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 8, 8, 1, 3, 6, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 2, 2, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 7, 8, 0, 6, 7, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 2, 2, 7, 3, 9, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 2, 9, 2, 7, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 2, 1, 11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 3, 8, 0, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 2, 2, 9, 10, 7, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 11, 8, 2, 3, 8, 10, 2, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 10, 6, 7, 1, 10, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 0, 0, 10, 8, 8, 10, 6, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 10, 0, 10, 6, 7, 0, 10, 7, 0, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 10, 7, 8, 10, 8, 9, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 6, 6, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 3, 11, 6, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 8, 8, 6, 4, 1, 0, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 4, 11, 4, 9, 1, 11, 4, 1, 11, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 8, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 0, 2, 8, 3, 2, 4, 8, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 4, 1, 2, 4, 2, 6, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 6, 6, 8, 11, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 2, 6, 3, 11, 6, 0, 3, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 10, 0, 10, 2, 4, 8, 6, 8, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 3, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 9, 3, 9, 10, 3, 10, 2, -1],
[1, 10, 6, 1, 6, 8, 6, 4, 8, 3, 1, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 10, 0, 10, 6, 0, 6, 4, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 3, 9, 10, 3, 10, 6, 3, 6, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1],
[4, 10, 6, 9, 10, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 9, 6, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 6, 8, 0, 3, 9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 5, 5, 0, 4, 11, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 7, 5, 8, 4, 5, 3, 8, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 7, 7, 2, 6, 9, 4, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 0, 7, 8, 0, 6, 7, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2, 7, 2, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 1, 8, 1, 2, 8, 2, 6, 8, 6, 7, -1],
[6, 7, 11, 5, 9, 4, 1, 10, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 7, 11, 6, 0, 3, 8, 2, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 6, 2, 5, 10, 2, 4, 5, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 7, 11, 3, 8, 4, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 2, 2, 5, 10, -1],
[9, 4, 5, 7, 10, 6, 7, 1, 10, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 4, 8, 0, 1, 8, 1, 10, 8, 10, 7, 7, 10, 6, -1],
[6, 7, 10, 10, 7, 3, 10, 3, 0, 10, 0, 4, 10, 4, 5, -1],
[4, 5, 8, 8, 5, 10, 8, 10, 6, 8, 6, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 6, 5, 9, 11, 6, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 9, 9, 3, 5, 5, 3, 11, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 8, 1, 8, 6, 8, 11, 6, 5, 1, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 6, 3, 6, 5, 3, 5, 1, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 6, 3, 6, 5, 9, 3, 6, 9, 3, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 6, 9, 0, 6, 0, 2, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 8, 8, 2, 6, 8, 6, 5, 8, 5, 1, 8, 1, 0, -1],
[1, 6, 5, 2, 6, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 9, 6, 5, 9, 11, 6, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 10, 5, 9, 0, 5, 0, 3, 5, 3, 6, 6, 3, 11, -1],
[10, 2, 5, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 8, 5, 8, 11, 5, 11, 6, -1],
[10, 2, 5, 5, 2, 3, 5, 3, 11, 5, 11, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 9, 6, 6, 9, 8, 6, 8, 3, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 10, -1],
[5, 9, 6, 6, 9, 0, 6, 0, 1, 6, 1, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 3, 0, 5, 10, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 5, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 0, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 1, 1, 8, 9, 6, 10, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 5, 2, 11, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 11, 11, 0, 2, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 6, 1, 0, 9, 3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 10, 11, 1, 2, 11, 9, 1, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 6, 6, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 1, 1, 6, 2, 8, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 9, 5, 6, 0, 9, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 9, 3, 9, 5, 6, 3, 9, 6, 3, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 6, 11, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 11, 5, 11, 0, 11, 8, 0, 1, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 3, 9, 11, 11, 9, 5, 11, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 9, 6, 11, 9, 11, 8, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 7, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 7, 9, 1, 0, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 5, 1, 4, 9, 1, 7, 4, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 7, 4, 8, 5, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 6, 4, 11, 7, 4, 2, 11, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 8, 3, 2, 11, 9, 1, 0, 10, 5, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 6, 7, 4, 9, 7, 9, 1, 7, 1, 11, 11, 1, 2, -1],
[2, 1, 6, 6, 1, 5, 8, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 0, 7, 0, 3, 5, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 4, 6, 9, 5, 6, 0, 9, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 6, 9, 9, 6, 2, 9, 2, 3, 9, 3, 7, 9, 7, 4, -1],
[4, 8, 7, 3, 6, 11, 3, 5, 6, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 4, 11, 11, 4, 0, 11, 0, 1, 11, 1, 5, 11, 5, 6, -1],
[4, 8, 7, 11, 3, 0, 11, 0, 9, 11, 9, 6, 6, 9, 5, -1],
[5, 6, 9, 9, 6, 11, 9, 11, 7, 9, 7, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 10, 10, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 4, 4, 10, 9, 3, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 10, 1, 0, 6, 10, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 4, 3, 4, 10, 4, 6, 10, 1, 3, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 10, 10, 4, 6, 3, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 2, 8, 2, 11, 9, 4, 10, 4, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 0, 10, 1, 0, 6, 10, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 11, 1, 1, 11, 8, 1, 8, 4, 1, 4, 6, 1, 6, 10, -1],
[4, 1, 9, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 0, 4, 1, 9, 4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 6, 0, 0, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 6, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 1, 11, 1, 9, 4, 11, 1, 4, 11, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 6, 1, 6, 11, 1, 11, 8, 1, 8, 0, -1],
[11, 3, 6, 3, 0, 6, 0, 4, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 6, 11, 4, 6, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 7, 6, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 9, 6, 9, 0, 3, 6, 9, 3, 6, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 0, 0, 7, 1, 1, 7, 6, 1, 6, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 7, 10, 1, 7, 1, 3, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 11, 10, 7, 6, 10, 8, 7, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[6, 10, 7, 7, 10, 9, 7, 9, 0, 7, 0, 2, 7, 2, 11, -1],
[11, 3, 2, 1, 0, 8, 1, 8, 7, 1, 7, 10, 10, 7, 6, -1],
[6, 10, 7, 7, 10, 1, 7, 1, 2, 7, 2, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 7, 6, 8, 6, 1, 6, 2, 1, 9, 8, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 9, 9, 3, 7, 9, 7, 6, 9, 6, 2, 9, 2, 1, -1],
[8, 7, 0, 7, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 2, 3, 6, 2, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, 6, 1, 9, 6, 9, 8, 6, 8, 7, -1],
[11, 7, 6, 1, 9, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 3, 6, 6, 3, 0, 6, 0, 8, 6, 8, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 7, 6, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 11, 11, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 11, 11, 5, 7, 0, 3, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 5, 5, 11, 10, 0, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 9, 3, 9, 1, 7, 11, 5, 11, 10, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 2, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 2, 8, 2, 10, 5, 8, 2, 5, 8, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 1, 5, 2, 10, 5, 3, 2, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 8, 2, 8, 9, 2, 9, 1, -1],
[1, 11, 2, 1, 7, 11, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 3, 1, 11, 2, 1, 7, 11, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 5, 0, 5, 11, 5, 7, 11, 2, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 9, 2, 9, 5, 2, 5, 7, 2, 7, 11, -1],
[5, 7, 1, 1, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 7, 0, 1, 7, 1, 5, 7, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 9, 5, 3, 5, 7, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 7, 8, 5, 7, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 5, 4, 8, 10, 5, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 4, 10, 4, 3, 4, 0, 3, 11, 10, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 9, 8, 5, 4, 8, 10, 5, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 4, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 11, 4, 11, 10, 4, 10, 5, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 0, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 1, 0, 3, 2, 10, 3, 10, 5, 3, 5, 8, 8, 5, 4, -1],
[10, 5, 2, 2, 5, 4, 2, 4, 9, 2, 9, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 5, 2, 5, 4, 8, 2, 5, 8, 2, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 11, 11, 1, 5, 11, 5, 4, 11, 4, 0, 11, 0, 3, -1],
[4, 8, 5, 5, 8, 11, 5, 11, 2, 5, 2, 0, 5, 0, 9, -1],
[5, 4, 9, 2, 3, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[4, 8, 5, 8, 3, 5, 3, 1, 5, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 5, 4, 1, 5, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 9, 3, 3, 9, 5, 3, 5, 4, 3, 4, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[5, 4, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 4, 7, 11, 9, 4, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 8, 11, 4, 7, 11, 9, 4, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 4, 1, 4, 7, 11, 1, 4, 11, 1, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 11, 4, 4, 11, 10, 4, 10, 1, 4, 1, 3, 4, 3, 8, -1],
[9, 4, 7, 9, 7, 2, 7, 3, 2, 10, 9, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 7, 7, 0, 2, 7, 2, 10, 7, 10, 9, 7, 9, 4, -1],
[1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 4, 10, 4, 7, 10, 7, 3, 10, 3, 2, -1],
[7, 8, 4, 10, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 7, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 0, 3, 2, 1, 9, 2, 9, 4, 2, 4, 11, 11, 4, 7, -1],
[7, 11, 4, 11, 2, 4, 2, 0, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 8, 2, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 7, 2, 7, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 3, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 4, 1, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 8, 1, 8, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 4, 7, 0, 4, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[7, 8, 4, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 11, 9, 9, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[0, 3, 9, 3, 11, 9, 11, 10, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 10, 0, 8, 10, 8, 11, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[10, 3, 11, 1, 3, 10, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 2, 8, 2, 10, 8, 10, 9, 8, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[9, 2, 10, 0, 2, 9, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 0, 10, 10, 0, 8, 10, 8, 3, 10, 3, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 10, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 11, 1, 9, 11, 9, 8, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[2, 1, 11, 11, 1, 9, 11, 9, 0, 11, 0, 3, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[11, 0, 8, 2, 0, 11, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[3, 11, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 8, 3, 9, 8, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[1, 9, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[8, 3, 0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],
[-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1],], dtype='i8')


@jitclass()
class Chunk_VBO():
    def __init__(self):       
        pass        
     
    def get_vertex_data(self, voxel_grid):         
        vertex_data = np.array([], dtype='f4')

        # get triangles                 
        for z in range(RES-1):
            for y in range(RES-1):
                for x in range(RES-1):
                    vertex_data = self.march_cube(np.array([x,y,z]), vertex_data, voxel_grid)

        # calculate normals of triangles
        normals = np.zeros(vertex_data.shape, dtype= np.float32)
        
        for i in range(0,vertex_data.shape[0],3):
            normals[i:i+2] = self.calculate_normal(vertex_data[i], vertex_data[i+1], vertex_data[i+2])
       
        vertex_data = np.hstack([normals, vertex_data])
        return vertex_data
    
    def calculate_normal(self, vertex_1, vertex_2, vertex_3):
        edge_1 = vertex_2 - vertex_1
        edge_2 = vertex_3 - vertex_1
        
        normal = np.cross(edge_1, edge_2)
        normal /= np.linalg.norm(normal)
        return normal
    
    def march_cube(self, pos, vertex_data, voxel_grid):
        triangulation = self.get_triangulation(pos[0],pos[1],pos[2], voxel_grid)
        
        for edge_index in triangulation:
            if edge_index < 0:
                break

            point_indeces = EDGES[edge_index]
            point1 = POINTS[point_indeces[0]]
            index = pos+point1
            v1 = voxel_grid[index[0]+RES*index[1]+RES*RES*index[2]]
            point2 = POINTS[point_indeces[1]]
            index = pos+point2
            v2 = voxel_grid[index[0]+RES*index[1]+RES*RES*index[2]]
            distance = v2 - v1
            vertex = point1 + ((point1 - point2) /distance *v1 )
            vertex += pos
            #vertex = (point1 + point2) /2 + pos * 1.1
            if vertex_data.size < 1:
                vertex_data = vertex
            else:
                vertex_data = np.vstack((vertex_data, vertex))
        return vertex_data

    def get_triangulation(self, x, y, z, voxel_grid):
        config_index = 0b00000000
        
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*y+RES*RES*z]<0) << 0
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*y+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 1
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*y+RES*RES*z]<0) << 2
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*y+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 3
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*z]<0) << 4
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[x+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 5
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*z]<0) << 6
        config_index |= int(voxel_grid[(x+1)+RES*(y+1)+RES*RES*(z+1)]<0) << 7
        
        return TRIANGULATIONS[config_index]
```

voxel_grid gets generated with this functions:

```
import numpy as np
import opensimplex as os

def get_voxel_grid(self, offset):
    voxel_grid = np.zeros(17 ** 3,np.float32)
        
    for z in range(17):
        for y in range(17):
            for x in range(17):
                voxel_grid[x+17*y+17*17*z] = self.surf(np.array([x,y,z])+offset)  
                    
        return voxel_grid

def surf(self, pos):
    x = pos[0]
    y = pos[1]
    z = pos[2]
        
    l1 = os.noise2((x+235223)/10,(z+2352)/10) * 2
    l2 = os.noise2((x+67221)/20,(z+1243)/20) * 4
    l3 = os.noise2((x+34)/28,(z+9548327)/28) * 3
        
    return y -10 +l1 +l2 +l3
```

When I run this I get following error message:

```
File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\experimental\jitclass\boxing.py", line 61, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Type of variable 'i' cannot be determined, operation: $phi424.1, location: c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\chunk_vbo.py (312)

File "chunk_vbo.py", line 312:
    def get_vertex_data(self, voxel_grid):
        <source elided>

        for i in range(0,vertex_data.shape[0],3):
        ^

- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
None

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'get_vertex_data') for instance.jitclass.Chunk_VBO#217ae88d050<>)
During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

I tried leaving out the calculation and just taking the np.zeros as the normals. That resulted in this message:

```
 File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\experimental\jitclass\boxing.py", line 61, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:
Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Type of variable 'normals' cannot be determined, operation: call $304load_attr.2($316load_attr.4, func=$304load_attr.2, args=[Var($316load_attr.4, chunk_vbo.py:310)], kws=[('dtype', Var($338load_attr.6, chunk_vbo.py:310))], vararg=None, varkwarg=None, target=None), location: c:\Users\anton\OneDrive\Desktop\Python Programme\Marching_Cubes\chunk_vbo.py (310)

File "chunk_vbo.py", line 310:
    def get_vertex_data(self, voxel_grid):
        <source elided>
        # calculate normals of triangles
        normals = np.zeros(vertex_data.shape, dtype= np.float32)
        ^

- Resolution failure for non-literal arguments:
None

During: resolving callee type: BoundFunction((<class 'numba.core.types.misc.ClassInstanceType'>, 'get_vertex_data') for instance.jitclass.Chunk_VBO#21b870011d0<>)
During: typing of call at <string> (3)


File "<string>", line 3:
<source missing, REPL/exec in use?>
```

When numba isnt used everything works perfectly.

I know there are other things I could improve but I wanted to programm it myself.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and put there minimal example (that we can run and throws mentioned error)?

Comment: I see the problem in `march_cube()`. The parameter `vertex_data` changes the dimension every call, so `numba` doesn't know how to compile this function. So maybe rethink  the structure of the code/calling. How would you do it in plain C?